# stranger exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-maven-plugin

I'm suffering this exception when run a instrumentation test:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f020001
```

**I'm sure the resource exists!**

My project structrue: a user proj **A**, and a lib project **B** (apklib).

In project B, I defined resource file `B-project/res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">my app</string>
    <string name="branding">release</string>
</resources>
```

Poject A depends on project B, and in project A, I override some properties (in `A-project/res/values/strings.xml`) defined in B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">For demo</string>
</resources>
```

**When packaging project A, things become stranger:**

In project A's generated resource, I found R.java:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static int app_name=0x7f020000;
        public static int branding=0x7f020001;
    }
}
```

I also found a `R.txt` in the `target` dir (I was using maven to manage the project):

```
int drawable icon 0x7f020000
int string app_name 0x7f030000
int string branding 0x7f030001
```

**Error:**

`R.branding` is **`0x7f020001`**, but the real resource id is: **`0x7f030001`**!

I think that's why I got the `Resources$NotFoundException`, But I've tried to clean and and re-compile the project many times, still got the same issue.

Comment: Try to change the name of the string value `name="app_name"` which might be conflicting because of same name while generating the resource file. And then try to clean and run project.

Comment: Tried but doesn't work.

Comment: It does work or not ?

Comment: have you tried to removed your R file.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: yeah, i've tried delete the whole target directory.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps carefully

1) Clean all your projects

2) Import the Specific R.java for your specifice projects.

3) Import specific classes only that you need don't import like this (It will throw err what you got), you are referencing more than one R.java file

```
   import org.project.a.R;
   import org.project.b.R;
```

If you are in project A then, import org.project.a.R; only not import org.project.b.R;

Suppose if you are using class from project b in A then you must be specific
  import org.project.b.ClassName;